# Tried to put a ProgressDialog in WebView of a AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display a WebView in AlertDialog and it works perfect, but also tried to put a ProgressDialog that says "Loading" as the URL of the WebView is loading.

The problem is that the ProgressDialog does not show but it does show the URL in the WebView charge.

Any help?

Thank you

```
@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                    //Toast.makeText(context, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /*nombre.setText("");
                    dni.setText("");
                    telefono.setText("");
                    email.setText("");*/



                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
                alert.setTitle("Title here");


                // Para colocar un loading

                pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading...",true);

                //--------------------------

                WebView wv = new WebView(getActivity());
                wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
                wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        if(pd.isShowing()&&pd!=null)
                        {
                            pd.dismiss();
                        }
                    }


                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);

                        return true;
                    }
                });

                alert.setView(wv);
                alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();




            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the call to `ProgressDialog.show()` to after the call to `alert.show()`.

```
...
alert.show();
pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading...", true);
```